# When you respawn the Ender Dragon, do the End Gateways reset?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

When you respawn the Ender Dragon, do the End Gateways reset?
I need to know because the current End Gateway spawns me under the Outer Island. By the way, it is on Realms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they do not reset.
However, every completed Ender Dragon fight creates a **new** End gateway portal floating within 75–100 blocks of the exit portal, up to a maximum of 20 gateway portals.

Source, [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Dragon#Drops).

Comment: I still need to know which is ahich, so that I don’t accidentally go through the wrong one and lose all my stuff.